# C++ stl :: sort() через компаратор

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка, stl

Почему не получается передавать в компаратор параметры по ссылке? Что туда вообще нужно передавать, а что не нужно? Как отсортировать двумерный массив при помощи такой функции и почему не рабоает этот код?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int maxN = 100, maxM = 150;
int n, m;

bool cmp ( int* A1, int* A2 ){
    int i = 0;
    while ( ( i < m ) && ( A1[i] == A2[i] ) )
        i++;
    if ( ( i == m ) || ( A1[i] > A2[i] ) )
        return true;
    return false;
}

int main(){
    int i, j, M[maxN][maxM];
    scanf(" %d %d ", &n, &m );
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        for ( j = 0; j < m; j++ )
            scanf( "%d", &M[i][j] );
    sort ( M, M + n, cmp );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы могли бы написать следующим образом, как, например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <functional>


int main()
{
    int a[][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 1, 3 } };

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( reinterpret_cast<std::array<int, 3> *>( std::begin( a ) ), 
               reinterpret_cast<std::array<int, 3> *>( std::end( a ) ), 
               std::less<>() );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( reinterpret_cast<std::array<int, 3> *>( std::begin( a ) ), 
               reinterpret_cast<std::array<int, 3> *>( std::end( a ) ), 
               std::greater<>() );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
1 2 3 
1 1 3 

1 1 3 
1 2 3 

1 2 3 
1 1 3
```

Как видите, сначала массив сортируется в порядке возрастания, а затем в порядке убывания, используя стандартные функциональные объекты `std::less` (его можно было бы вообще не использовать, так как вместо него применялся бы оператор `operator` <, объявленный для класса `std::array`) и `std::greater`.

Проблема в том, что интерпретация указателя на одномерный массив как указателя на объект `std::array` а затем обращение к элементам объекта через этот указатель, является не совсем корректной в C++, хотя программа успешно отработала.

Что касается массивов, то проблема заключается не в том, что к ним нельзя применить функцию `std::swap`, ее как раз можно успешно применять к массивам, а в том, что сортируемые элементы должны быть `MoveConstructible` и  `MoveAssignable`, то есть в приложении к массивам это означает, что массивы должны быть присваиваемыми или инициализируемыми с помощью других массивов. Однако для массивов отсутствует оператор перемещающего присваивания и конструктор перемещения.

В показанном мной примере с `std::array` этой проблемы не существует, так как этот класс имеет неявно определенные компилятором оператор перемещающего присваивания и конструктор перемещения.

Я привел этот пример для того, что вы могли бы объявить массив объектов `std::array<int, maxM>`. Например

```
#include <array>

//...

std::array<int, maxM> M[maxN];
```

и тогда без проблем могли бы вызывать функцию `std::sort`.

Поэтому если вы хотите отсортировать именно двумерный массив, то либо функцию сортировки вам придется писать самому, либо использовать стандартную C функцию `qsort`, объявленную в заголовочном файле `<cstdlib>`.

Я покажу упрощенный вариант, когда количество сравниваемых элементов в строке массива совпадает с размерностью строки массива. В вашем случае это не так, поэтому в функциях-корпоратарах вы должны учитывать число реально сравниваемых элементов. Эти числа можно включить в эти функции с помощью вызова внутри других функций, которые возвращают заданное значение числа реально сравниваемых элементов в строке массива.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>


const int maxN = 2, maxM = 3;

int cmp_ascending( const void *lhs, const void *rhs )
{
    const int ( *a )[maxM]  = reinterpret_cast<const int ( * )[maxM]>( lhs ); 
    const int ( *b )[maxM]  = reinterpret_cast<const int ( * )[maxM]>( rhs );

    const int *first1 = *a, *last1 = *a + maxM;
    const int *first2 = *b;

    while ( first1 != last1 && *first1 == *first2 ) ++first1, ++first2;

    return first1 == last1 ? 0 : ( *first1 > *first2 ) - ( *first1 < *first2 );
}    

int cmp_descending( const void *lhs, const void *rhs )
{
    const int ( *a )[maxM]  = reinterpret_cast<const int ( * )[maxM]>( lhs ); 
    const int ( *b )[maxM]  = reinterpret_cast<const int ( * )[maxM]>( rhs );

    const int *first1 = *a, *last1 = *a + maxM;
    const int *first2 = *b;

    while ( first1 != last1 && *first1 == *first2 ) ++first1, ++first2;

    return first1 == last1 ? 0 : ( *first2 > *first1 ) - ( *first2 < *first1 );
}    


int main()
{
    int a[][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 1, 3 } };

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::qsort( a, maxN, sizeof( *a ), cmp_ascending );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::qsort( a, maxN, sizeof( *a ), cmp_descending );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет таким же, как и в предыдущей программе:

```
1 2 3 
1 1 3 

1 1 3 
1 2 3 

1 2 3 
1 1 3
```

Вы могли бы обойти эти трудности, если бы динамически выделили массив указателей на одномерные массивы.

В противном случае, если вы не хотите возиться с массивами, то лучше использовать стандартный класс `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Итак, у вас есть следующие четыре возможности.

Первая - это объявить массив объектов класса `std::array`

```
std::array<int, maxM> M[maxN];
```

В этом случае никаких проблем с сортировкой не будет.

Вторая - это объявить массив указателей, а затем каждый указатель массива инициализировать адресом динамически выделенного одномерного массива. Например

```
int * M[mxN];

for ( int i = 0; i < maxN; i++ ) M[i] = new int[maxM];
```

В этом случае также никаких проблем с вызовом `std::sort` не будет.

Третья - оставить объявление массива таким, какое оно есть в вашей программе, и использовать стандартную C функцию `qsort`, объявленную в заголовке `<cstdlib>`

Четвертая - использовать стандартный контейнер `std::vector`, включив следующее объявление в программу

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> M( maxN, std::vector<int>( maxM ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело не в компараторе, а в том, что `std::sort` не может сортировать массив массивов, т.к. она не может присвоить элементам массива новые значения (нельзя присвоить массив массиву).

Используйте `vector<vector<int>>`.

Comment: Проблема сортировки массива не имеет отношение к функции std:;swap. Как раз эту функцию вы можете успешно применять к массивам. Проблема связана с тем, что массивы не являются MoveConstrutibel и MoveAssignable.